# Solution for no-cache image not working with background-image

Tags: css, image, caching, background

I have to use for images:

```
BANNER.jpg?V='.time();
```

This is because I need to simulate a no-cached image to allow me to update image immediately. Otherwise I would have to refresh a few times before the new image kicks in.

BUT I cannot use this with background image.

```
background:url('./BANNER.jpg?V=23049230492') repeat 50% 50%;
```

The image is non-recognizable at all! How can I make it recognize?

Comment: Can you provide an example jsfiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the fact that the '?' was turned into '%3F'. Solution was to use

```
urlencode
```

similar to this

```
background:url('<?php echo urlencode(basename(glob('../PAGE/'.$USER_CODE.'/BANNER.*')[0])); ?>')
```

which returns

```
BANNER.jpg%3fV=1395268979
```